# connecting female male USB to samsung tablet android

Tags: android, connection

is there a certain setting on android devices (samsung) that you can set too allow USBs to connect to it?

Comment: What do you mean USBs? A flash memory through an OTG wire or connecting the device to a PC through USB?

Comment: flash memory through OTG wire

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any settings to activate that option in an Android Device. You have to check two things about your device to be able to use the OTG function though. The device hardware and firmware (+Android Version) must be OTG capable. There are some Android apps that allow you to check if your device is OTG compliant. Look for com.app.usbotgchecker.apk, StickMount.apk and net.shajul.usbotg.apk